# How to determine if libpthread and libthread_db match?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, pthreads, shared-libraries

Is there a way to determine whether given `libpthread` and `libthread_db` found on the system match?

Only way i know is to try and launch gdb on the program built with libpthread library. Is there any other?

Comment: `file` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Damato has a blog post [explaining](http://timetobleed.com/notes-about-an-odd-esoteric-yet-incredibly-useful-library-libthread_db/) how to load `libthread_db` in C to inspect another process running `libpthread`.  If this succeeds then you know that these libraries match.  Unfortunately to do this you need to write a significant chunk of a debugger including reading from the process's memory and searching its symbol tables, so this isn't a simple answer.

Comment: that's something to consider

Comment: the link is out of date.

Comment: @flyingdutchman Thanks, I had a stray "https:" at the end - fixed now.